# Speculable or Speculatable?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, inflections

In the field of programming, we know a function is "safe to *speculatively* execute" if it has no side-effects.

Is there a single word which can describe this attribute? *Speculable*? *Speculatable*? Something else?

(I prefer to avoid anything which does not include any variation of "speculate", in fear of drifting away from a term which is familiar in this context).

Comment: Well, most certainly not *speculable*. Much like you don't say *unlable* for "unlockable" or *remable* for "removable".

Comment: @RegDwighт well, I'm asking because [Google's results for Speculatable](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=speculatable) actually suggest "speculable" instead, and both words have roughly equal amounts of Google results.

Comment: OneLook dictionary finds *[speculate](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Speculate&ls=b)* in 42 dictionaries; *[Speculable](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Speculable&ls=b)* in 1 dictionary; and *[Speculatable](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Speculatable&ls=b)* in no dictionaries. Try looking through some dictionary entries for *speculate* and see if they have any adjective that would fit your purpose.

Comment: I am trying to understand what "speculatable" would mean. Able to be speculated upon? That doesn't seem to be of any use to you in the above context. The attribute of "speculatively executable" is something entirely different, and doesn't have a single word.

Comment: @MattЭллен I'd say "able to speculate upon" is close enough to the meaning I want.

Comment: As you mentioned programming: _idempotent_ functions are 'safe to speculatively execute' as they don't have side effects

Comment: Use *speculatable*, better still, *speculateable* if you must -- this term is recognized in computer science. *Speculable* is not recommended for general/ technical English writing. See also: answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Specule* is a proper word, a noun, found in dictionaries, unrelated in usage and etymology to the word *speculate* in general English.

*Speculable/ speculeable* cannot be used to imply *speculatable*, though some instances may be found in writing.

Note that the usage of *speculable* in a sense related to speculate is found essentially in philosophical discourse:

> Thomas calls the objects of practical and speculative philosophy, respectively, the operable and the **speculable**. [emphasis mine]

(Ralph McInerny,  *Hist. W. Phil. V.II: XIII C - [Chap 6, St Thomas Aquinas](http://www3.nd.edu/Departments/Maritain/etext/hwp220.htm)*)

> Data **speculatable** processor having reply architecture *[US 5966544 A](http://www.patentstorm.us/patents/5966544.html)*
>   A microprocessor having a replay architecture with an execution core for performing data speculation in executing an instruction, …

[LLVM Commits List:](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.cvs/153473)

> I'd like Eric to take a quick look and agree that marking debug intrinsics **speculatable** is sane. (Yes they already are, but that doesn't mean it's sane. I also want Eric to know that '**speculatable**' is going to start showing up in his debug info.)

Also, *non-speculatable*, *speculatability*, *non-speculatability*:

> The method and apparatus are employed within a microprocessor capable of generating speculative memory accesses instructions. Certain instructions access memory locations containing **speculatable** information while others access memory locations containing **non-secpulatable** information. Memory-type values indicating the **speculatability** or **non-speculatability** of memory locations are stored within a translation lookaside buffer. (Method and apparatus for handling speculative memory access operations [US 5956753](http://www.patentlens.net/patentlens/patents.html?patnums=US_5956753))

Answer (score 1):

Either of the suggested terms could arise via ordinary methods of word formation, and would be properly understood by most people, and in particular by people familiar with the ideas of speculative execution.  I prefer *speculable* and regard it as a more-civilized word than *speculatable*.

Note that the meaning of *speculable* suggested at 
[a wordnik link](http://www.wordnik.com/words/speculable) in TrevorD's comment is “knowable”, while [an older dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=6TsMAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA614&lpg=PA614&dq=speculable+meaning&source=bl&ots=5VeAYs4Ok0&sig=xBfZhJvkyuOrGMo2BRae1-tbpio&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vGzxUfG7HsqFiAK5j4DwDw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=speculable%20meaning&f=false) suggests the meaning  “Capable of being seen”, which is related to the second example shown by wordnik.

However, multiple authors ([1](http://books.google.com/books?id=srgjhIJU2wkC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=speculable+meaning&source=bl&ots=cNtXk9S6_1&sig=_k6fY9IgOYQ68srSThcR2RU_cKY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vGzxUfG7HsqFiAK5j4DwDw&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=speculable%20meaning&f=false),[2](http://www3.nd.edu/Departments/Maritain/etext/hwp220.htm)) have used *speculable* to refer to things that are speculative, or  things that can be speculated about; both of those senses apply reasonably well to speculative execution matters, and are consistent with the first sense shown in OED1 (1919):

> a. Obs. rare. ... f. specular* to SPECULATE. ... 
>     That admits of speculation ; speculative.